# WP7 SilverLight TabControl not attached to VS toolbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I downloaded and installed SilverLight 4.0 tools for WP7 but I am unable to attach some controls. When "choose items" option on toolbox, I search for a System.Windows.Controls library and, once attached, I can see tabBar object properly selected and ready to be attached. However, after accept, control does not appear on toolbox. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no TabControl in the Windows Phone toolkit.

You've probably selected a dll that also contains a System.Windows.Controls namespace, that is not compatible with Windows Phone 7 development.

**EDIT**

The article referenced [dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-tabcontrol-windows-phone](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-tabcontrol-windows-phone)
uses the TabControl from the standard Silverlight controls. The way I read the article, the intention is to add a reference to the library mentioned to a Silverlight for WP project (i.e. "Add Reference" from the "References" node of a project), and working from there.

It won't show up on the toolbox, that's for sure.

Comment: I think that it is. I found some references talking about this silverlight control for wp7 and I am sure that I am adding proper reference... http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-tabcontrol-windows-phone

Comment: @Jaume: The article is talking about the TabControl in the standard Silverlight toolkit. I've updated my answer.